# How to stop class from being redefined when using multiple files in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, header-files

I am using multiple files for class definitions and namespaces. The main.cpp file which contains the main() function requires the use of one of the classes, as does the namespace math in my "math.cpp" file, so they both contain #include "Vect.h", which has the declaration of the class. However, as the main() also requires use of the math namespace, it has #include "math.cpp". If I try to run this, the compiler tells me I have already defined class Vect in main.obj with error code LNK2005.

I assume this means I need to stop the math.cpp or main.cpp from including Vect.h again somehow, so I tried surrounding the Vect.h file with a

```
    #ifndef VECT
    #define VECT
    //CODE
    #endif
```

However this did not work and now I'm out of ideas

In Vect.h, I have the declaration of the class Vect (it is defined in Vect.cpp)

```cpp
#pragma once

class Vect {
private:
    float x;
        float y;
        float z;
public:
    Vect(float a, float b, float c);
    //Some other functions..
};
```

Main creates 2 Vect objects and uses the math namespace to create a third

```
#include "Vect.h"
#include "math.cpp"
int main() {
    Vect a(1, 2, 3);
    Vect b(0.5, -1, 4);
    Vect c = vct::subtract(a, b);
```

The math.cpp file:

```
#include "Vect.h"
namespace vct {
    Vect subtract(Vect a, Vect b) {
        Vect output(0, 0, 0);
        //function code
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: `#include "math.cpp"` is your bug. Never include a `.cpp` file. Instead make this file part of your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not include `.cpp` files in another file.

If your `main.cpp` requires some declaration from your `math.cpp`, provide a `math.h` with that declaration and include it in both:

```
#include "Vect.h"
namespace vct {
    Vect subtract(Vect, Vect);
}
```

Note however that `math.h` is a bad name because it may conflict with the standard header of the same name, so try to rename it to something different.

Include guards like you show at the beginning of your question (or alternatively `#pragma once` which isn't that portable) do always belong in each header file (with different macro names for each). Otherwise you will get more problems down the line.